# Why is $r \sin(\phi) \cos(\omega x) +r \cos(\phi) \sin(\omega x) = r \sin(\omega x + \phi)$?

Tags: trigonometry

As the title says: How do I arrive from the left to the right side in the equality $$r \sin(\phi) \cos(\omega x) +r \cos(\phi) \sin(\omega x) = r \sin(\omega x + \phi)$$
where $x\in\mathbb R$, $r,\omega > 0$ and $\phi \in [0,2\pi]$?

I've never been good at trigonometry and this is the first time I'm working with this stuff in years. So an additional question would be: What are good resources to get practice with these kind of calculations?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#Sum_and_difference_formulas

Comment: As Wikipedia suggests, the easiest derivation of this is to use Euler's Formula $re^{i\theta} = r(\cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta))$. Then use $e^{i(\omega x + \phi)} = e^{i\omega x} e^{i\phi}$ and expand the left- and right-hand sides. The same idea works for all the trigonometric sum/product formulae.

Comment: If you want to do trigonometry, memorize the formulas. Well, not really, though, I personally know only couple of them by heart, but I'm aware of the existence of other formulas and their approximate forms, so I can recognise immediately when they are used and if I really need to, I can just look up the precise statement.

Comment: There is also simple geometric proof of the $\sin(\alpha+\beta)=\sin\alpha\cos\beta+\cos\alpha\sin\beta$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the addition formula for the $\sin$ function is $\sin(a+b)=\sin(a)\cos(b)+\cos(a)\sin(b)$: by making the substitution $a=\phi,\ b=\omega x$ we get $\sin(\phi+\omega x)=\sin(\phi)\cos(\omega x)+\cos(\phi)\sin(\omega x).$ By multiplying both sides by $r$ we get $r\sin(\phi)\cos(\omega x)+r\cos(\phi)\sin(\omega x)=r\sin(\phi+\omega x)$, as desired.